# Realm ignoredProperties not working for compound primary key

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to create compound primary key from two keys. Using lazy for compoundKey will raise an exception - `either remove lazy or add to ignore property list`

So when I try to add ignore property list I am getting following exception - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Primary key property 'compoundKey' does not exist on object 'Collection'`

Removing lazy and setting the empty string will add empty key and hence single row which will treat all primary key value as empty.

This is my code

```
class Collection : Object {
    @objc dynamic var count: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var nextURL: String?
    @objc dynamic var previousURL: String?

    func setCompoundNextURL(nextURL: String) {
        self.nextURL = nextURL
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    func setCompoundTourPreviousURL(previousURL: String) {
        self.previousURL = previousURL
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    public dynamic lazy var compoundKey: String = self.compoundKeyValue()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["compoundKey"]
    }

    func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
        return "\(nextURL ?? "")\(previousURL ?? "")"
    }
}
```

Please help. I am not able to figure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell Realm to use an ignored property as a primary key. An ignored property isn't persisted to the Realm. The primary key property *must* be persisted to the Realm. Additionally, the primary key property's value cannot be changed after the object is created. For this reason I'd suggest computing the value inside a convenience initializer and assigning it to the property at that time.

Comment: Okay my basic concern here is to have compound primary key, but lazy isn't working.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve by using lazy, or why you're trying to ignore the primary key property.